# Decimal vs Money datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

`Money` datatype has been used for column like `VendorHours`, `OverTime`, `Expenses` in one of table.

I am designing another table which is related to this same table and will have similar columns but I am thinking about using the `decimal` datatype instead of `money` as decimal is more precise.

Later I found out that money datatype is being used because it take 8 bytes where as decimal would use 10 for 10-19 Precision.

Columns like Visit Hour, OverTime would fit into decimal with Precision 9 and would take only 5 bytes. So is this a good idea to use decimal(9,2) instead of money?

I will be doing a lot of calculation on those fields inside the stored procedure for reports.

Answer (score 5):

It depends... if you're not going to do anything to the values other than add or subtract... no problems. If you're going to do anything else (like multiply or divide), you'll need at least 4 decimal places to do the calculations without loosing overall accuracy.

`MONEY` more accurately represents the real world situation, where each value is rounded to the nearest cent as calculated, then the average is again rounded. In a long calculation chain, the difference can wind up being considerably larger than one cent ... but due to the business-logic constraint that all intermediate values contain non-fractional cents, the `MONEY` result will be accurate, whereas the "more precise" `DECIMAL` will not.